# Groovy-Json example - map object returns null value

Tags: json, groovy

I'm practicing this example to validate some book price out of a json response but I'm encountering error:

Exception thrown

> java.lang.AssertionError: Unable to find the title A Nice Novel. Expression: (books instanceof java.util.Map). Values: books = null
>       at validateBookPrice.verifyBookPrice(validateBookPrice.groovy:29)
>       at validateBookPrice$_run_closure1.doCall(validateBookPrice.groovy:22)
>       at validateBookPrice.run(validateBookPrice.groovy:20)

**Here are my code examples:**

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

//sample json response
def obj = '''{ "bookStore" : [ { "category" : "novel",
    "author" : "Mr. J Thomas",
    "title" : "A Nice Novel",
    "price" : "$25.00"
  },
  { "category" : "biography",
    "author" : "Mrs.Jones",
    "title" : "A Biography of Mr. Jones",
    "price": "$35.00"
  }]}'''

 def bookData= slurper.parseText(obj)

//sample book prices to be validated
def books= [ "A Nice Novel" : "\$25.00", "A Biography of Mr. Jones" :    "\$35.00"]
books.each{key, value ->
     def expected_value ="${value}"
     verifyBookPrice(bookData, key, expected_value)
}



def verifyBookPrice(bookData, title, expected_value) {
       Map books = bookData.bookStore.find{it.key == title }
       assert books instanceof Map:"Unable to find the title $title"
       String actual_value = books.price as String
       assert actual_value == expected_value:"The value of field $field is  $actual_value, expecting $expected_value"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed script:

**Changed from :** `bookData.bookStore.find{it.key == title }`

**To :** `bookData.bookStore.find{it.title == title}`

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

//sample json response
def obj = '''{ "bookStore" : [ { "category" : "novel",
    "author" : "Mr. J Thomas",
    "title" : "A Nice Novel",
    "price" : "$25.00"
  },
  { "category" : "biography",
    "author" : "Mrs.Jones",
    "title" : "A Biography of Mr. Jones",
    "price": "$35.00"
  }]}'''

def bookData= slurper.parseText(obj)

def verifyBookPrice(bookData, title, expected_value) {
       Map book = bookData.bookStore.find{it.title == title}
       assert book instanceof Map:"Unable to find the title $title"
       String actual_value = book.price as String
       assert actual_value == expected_value:"The value of field $title is  $actual_value, expecting $expected_value"
}

//sample book prices to be validated
def books= [ "A Nice Novel" : "\$25.00", "A Biography of Mr. Jones" :    "\$35.00"]
books.each{key, value ->
     verifyBookPrice(bookData, key, value)
}
```

You may quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5098904710283264)</kbd>

Comment: I assume you meant `find{it.title == title}`...  Answer updated :-D

Comment: Thank you @tim_yates for updating. It might be missed out as parameter and property name are equal.

Comment: @Rao,  I would much appreciate again if you could please help me fixing the 2nd problem in my reply post? Adding comments here as I'm not quite sure my 2nd post would notify you:)

Comment: Looks like you have not used the solution that is provided as answer which fixed in the above already. Give it a try.

Comment: there was another issue in the second assertion which  is fixed in the answer as well.

Comment: @Rao - my apologies... I had just changed in the line where I was getting error for null. It's all good now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mojo1012, [appreciate if you accept it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)